# Scipy and the beta distribution: is is possible to change the range of x values?

Tags: python, scipy, distribution

The beta distribution is usually specified in the interval x = [0,1]. However different x bounds can also be specified (see figure below). How can I refine the python code below to reproduce the figure?

[image]

My attempt (uncomplete!):

```
from scipy.stats import beta
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
a =  2
b = 2
x = np.arange (0.01, 1, 0.01)
y = beta.pdf(x,a,b)
plt.plot(x,y)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. But how should I proceed to only keep alpha as a free parameter, like in the example figure?

Comment: What is the function that is being plotted in that graph? Do you have a link to a page containing it?

Answer (score 9):

You could modify the `loc` and `scale` of beta function.

```
from scipy.stats import beta
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
a = 2
b = 2
x = np.arange (-50, 50, 0.1)
y = beta.pdf(x,a,b, scale=100, loc=-50)
plt.plot(x,y)
```

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure what the alpha parameter is supposed to represent.

I got the function to produce three different shapes by varying the parameters, but it doesn't really make much sense to me. On the off-chance that you might understand the math but not know how to produce multiple lines on the same plot, here is some code that at least does that.

```
from scipy.stats import beta
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
a =  2
b = 2
x = np.linspace(0, 1.0, 100)
y1 = beta.pdf(x, 2.75, 2.75)
y2 = beta.pdf(x, 3.25, 3.25)
y3 = beta.pdf(x, 3, 3)
plt.plot(x, y1, "-", x, y2, "r--", x, y3, "g--")
```

This code gives the following graphical output:

[image: Out]

Is that anything like what you are looking for?

*By the way, I used `linspace()` rather than your `arange()` because it returns a given number of intervals by interpolation, always useful when floating-point is in use. There is one more element in `np.arange (0.01, 1.00001, 0.01)` than in `np.arange (0.01, 1, 0.01)`.*